# ls after cd in tcsh?

Tags: ls, alias, cd-command, tcsh

I cannot seem to find an answer to this question. In my `.bash_profile` I have this line:

```
cd() { builtin cd "$@"; ll; }
```

which executes `ll` every time I change directories. I would like this functionality in tcsh as well, but I have not the foggiest of how to add this to my `.cshrc` file.  They yelled at me for posting this in stackoverflow, and sent me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual page for [`tcsh`](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/top.html) is the place to start, because it gives an example which can be adapted:

> For example, alias print 'pr !* | lpr'' defines a *``command''* (*`print'*) which pr(1)s its arguments to the line printer.

Thus:

```
alias cd 'cd \!* ; ls'
```

This happens to work (see the section *[Alias substitution](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Alias_substitution.html)*) because `tcsh` detects the use of `cd` in the alias and stops recurring:

> Alias substitution is repeated until the first word of the command has no alias. If an alias substitution does not change the first word (as in the previous example) it is flagged to prevent a loop. Other loops are detected and cause an error.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you!!  Glad it's not a builtin function, making this so much easier to do.